# Reading of project.properties file in jsp in hybris

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a key in my project.properties as `userKey=value`

I wanna read the value in jsp with using configservice in java. Is there a possibility to do it?

I tried to use

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<spring:message code="label.username"/>
<spring:message code="label.password"/>
```

but it failed with below error :

> WARN  [hybrisHTTP30] [DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry] Error
>   processing component tag. currentComponent
>   [MerchGenericMediaComponentModel (8800615040060@15)] exception:
>   javax.serv
>       Sep 14, 2017 2:31:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>       javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'userKey' for locale 'en'.
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
>               at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mobile.cms.th.merchgenericmediacomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(merchgenericmediacomponent_jsp.java:472)
>               at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mobile.cms.th.merchgenericmediacomponent_jsp._jspService(merchgenericmediacomponent_jsp.java:130)
>               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
>               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:603)
>              at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:542)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>               at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

Comment: As `dj_frunza` explained in the answer you should use `base.properties`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work. Use the below snippet in the `Jsp` and replace the 'propertykey' with the one which you want to retrieve from `local.properties` or `project.properties`.

```
${jalosession.tenant.config.getParameter('propertykey')}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really only want to set some language properties than you should definitly use the:

```
\web\webroot\WEB-INF\messages\base.properties
```

for this configuration. Therefore this file was made. But if you have some other properties that you want to use in you *.jsp file you can use:

```
<spring:eval expression="T(de.hybris.platform.util.Config).getParameter('your.code')" var="myVar" scope="page" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try putting your labels(in this case *userKey=value*) in ***base.properties*** file (or *base_en.properties*) instead of **project.properties**

**base.properties** is used for I18n, while

**project.properties** is used to configure ports, build environment, JVM options, etc...